# Executing commands on the Ansible host from a handler

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to implement the following scenario in Ansible (v1.9.1):

1. Ansible connects to remote host and uses `su` to become `root`.
2. Ansible host *fetches* remote configuration file that it is about to clobber.
3. Ansible host stores *adds* the just-fetched file to a Git repository that contains the destination directory using `git add ...`.
4. Ansible host *commits* the just-fetched file using `git commit ...` and an appropriate commit message.

Now, (1) is fully supported since v1.9.0.1 and (2) is made very easy with the [fetch module](http://docs.ansible.com/fetch_module.html) - by default it even stores the files under a host-specific sub-directory.

However, I have not been able to figure out (3) and (4). Ideally, I would like Ansible to just execute a local command as the user that started it in the first place. I *could* create a wrapper shell script to do that, but that seems quite contrary to the Ansible way of doing things.

Most posts on the Internet suggest using the `local_action` module. `local_action`, however, seems to be completely overkill for my purpose - it tries to access the host with proper privilege escalation. As a result it fails:

> fatal: [host00 -> 127.0.0.1] => Internal Error: this module does not support running commands via su

This is what my handler looks like currently:

```
- name: stage-archive-file
  become: false
  su: false
  local_action: command git -C {{ playbook_dir }} add storage/archive
  notify: commit-archive-file
```

`local_action` seems to completely ignore my attempts to make it *not* use `su`, although I am not sure if this is something related to this specific module or to the `su` method in general.

Is there a simpler way to just execute a command from the ansible process? Alternatively, is it possible to somehow get `local_action` to work?

---

There seems to be a [related Ansible issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10906) that may be preventing `local_action` from working correctly in this case. Apparently `local_action` and `delegate_to` retain some connection settings from the "parent" task, even if those are completely invalid for the delegated host.

Comment: I suspect, but I'm not 100% sure, that you've run into a bug that was fixed with [this change](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/10559).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: As far as I can tell from a visual inspection of the Ansible v1.9.1 source code that patch is already applied. Timing (Apr. 2 vs Apr. 28) also seems to suggest this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I expect that the [root cause](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10906) of this problem will be fixed in a future Ansible version, I rolled out my own solution. Basically I modified/hacked a stripped-down connection plugin for Ansible that simply executes a command on the host. The process was as follows:

- In the playbook directory create a subdirectory named `connection_plugins`.
- Copy the `local.py` connection plugin from the Ansible installation (e.g. `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/connection_plugins/local.py`) to the newly created subdirectory with a different name such as `execute.py`.
- Edit `connection_plugins/execute.py` and remove the code sections that relate to the privilege escalation methods.
- Add an entry for `localhost` in the inventory file with the parameter `ansible_connection=execute`.

The last step would need to be modified if `local_action` should indeed use a  privilege escalation method for some tasks. In that case it is possible to leave the entry for `localhost` (if any) unmodified, define another alias with the `execute` connection type and then use `delegate_to:` instead of `local_action:` in the task definitions.